# Inserting data using SET and NOW() with node.js to mySQL Db

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert

Currently this is my code, which inserts the new_item correctly

```
var new_item = {id_user: id, id_restaurant: id_rest, type: 3, date: date};

connection.query("INSERT INTO table SET ?", [new_item], function(err, results) {
    if(err){
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But now I don't want to send the date with it, I want to use `SET ?` and do something like`date = NOW()` basically I want to insert this:

```
    var new_item = {id_user: id, id_restaurant: id_rest, type: 3};
```

and  use `date = NOW()-INTERVAL 6 hour` to assign the date.

EDIT: I posted I only wanted `Now()` but actually I want to set Interval it before inserting.

Comment: I don't think I'm mixing anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is better to use moment.js.

You can use Date.now which returns current timestamp(milliseconds), so make sure to format it. The code is as follows:

```
var a = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Please let me know if this works out

Comment: What if I want a certain timezone? I want central time response.

Comment: There is another module called moment-timezone which you'll have to install along with moment and according to their docs something like this should work out:  moment.tz('2016-01-01', 'America/Chicago').format('z')....... check their docs @http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10) + " " + new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 19)
```

same as `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'`

Answer (score 0):

Using NOW() is executed by the database interpreter and sets the database time.

You could create a new variable to use in your SQL statement and set the wanted content to that one.

```
var new_item1 = {id_user: id, id_restaurant: id_rest, type: 3, date: date};
var new_item2 = {id_user: new_item1.id_user, ...};
connection.query("INSERT INTO table SET ?", [new_item2], function(err, results) {
    if(err){
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you could configure your column to set the NOW() timestamp as default.

Comment: That's what i did, but I want to do seomthing like `NOW()-INTERVAL 6 HOUR`  because my server will not allow me to change the system time, so default doesn't actually solve it.